# Unicode character for superscript shows a square box: ࠚ

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Using the following code to create a Unicode string:

```
wchar_t HELLO[20];
wsprintf(HELLO, TEXT("%c"), 0x2074);
```

When I display this onto a Win32 Control like a Text box or a button it gets mapped to a [] Square. 
How do I fix this ?
I tried compiling with both Eclipse(MinGW) and Microsoft Visual C++ (2010). 
Also, `UNICODE is defined at the top`

### Edit:

I think it might be something to do with my system, because when I visit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts
some of the unicode characters don't appear.

Comment: I'd try using `(wchar_t)2074` or `TEXT('\x81a')`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still the same [].

Comment: Nothing to do with encoding. A lot to do with _fonts_

Comment: Let me guess that you are on XP. Vista/7 have much more capable fonts out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font you are using does not contain a glyph for that character. You will likely need to install some new fonts to overcome this deficiency.

The character you have picked out is 'SAMARITAN MODIFIER LETTER EPENTHETIC YUT' (U+081A). Perhaps you were after U+2074, i.e. 'SUPERSCRIPT FOUR' (U+2074). You need hex for that: 0x2074.

Note you changed the question to read `0x2074` but the original version read `2074`. Either way, if you see a box that indicates your font is missing that glyph.

Comment: Suggest a font then ?

And, if I'm writing an application, then how do I ensure that the user's system has the same font ?
Isnt there a font that ships with windows that has superscripts and subscripts ?

-> 0x2074 also shows []

Comment: Im writing a desktop app not a web app.

Comment: @viraj: copy the character from a web page, for example http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2074/index.htm. Paste it into WordPad. Drop down the font list and mouse over the fonts; as you pause over each font name, the character will be displayed in that font and you'll easily see which ones support it.

Comment: @viraj: try the Symbola font from [here](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/). You'll have to ship it with the installation of your app.

Comment: But it's still odd that it doesn't work. How is word still able to use superscripts and subscripts ?

Comment: @viraj Word draws superscripts and subscripts itself. Remember that it can do that for any characters, not just the ones that happen to have dedicated code points.

Answer (score 2):

The characters you are getting from Wikipedia are expressed in hexadecimal, so your code should be:

```
wchar_t HELLO[20];
wsprintf(HELLO, TEXT("%c"), (wchar_t)0x2074);  // or TEXT('\x2074')
```

If it still doesn't work, it's a font problem; if you need a pan-Unicode font, it seems that Code2000 is one of the most complete out there.

---

Funny fact: the character that has the *decimal* code 2074 (i.e. hex 81a) <s>seems to [actually be a box](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/081a/index.htm) (or</s> it's such a strange beast that even the image outline at FileFormat.Info is wrong<s>)</s>. :)

For the curious ones: it turns out that 0x081a is this thing:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid mistake. I corrected it to 0x2074 but it still shows a smaller []